# How to easily crossfade (change) 40 images in HTML5? e. g. make a light animation

Tags: html, animation, image, frames

For example, I have 40 slightly different images. Basically, that's frames for animation. And all I need is to let them change each other through crossfade on hover.

Example:
-user hovers the image with his pointer --> animation starts
img1..img2..img3..img4..img5.............img40 (every image shows for 0.20 sec then other one appears, then image stuck on the last frame)
-user moves the pointer away --> animation goes back to the first frame in the same way.

Is there a good tool to make such an animation in an easy way? And to make final image size small enough..

Thanks